# Does TortoiseSVN download a local/temp copy of SVN logs when it displays them or does it merely display the result without making a local copy?

Tags: svn, logging, tortoisesvn, history

TortoiseSVN allows you to view logs.  When you do so, does it create a temp/local copy on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you open tortoisesvn settings there is an option labelled Log Caching and a checkbox to enable (should be on by default) along with some other options.

There is an excellent article here for a previous version but still applies.
http://tortoisesvn.net/logcacheuuids.html